# how to parse a cscope's database

Tags: cscope

Is there any way I can parse the cscope's database? I'm using windows, and I can't find any article about the data format of cscope's database, every article is about VIM or EMacs.

Answer (score 3):

You can find it here. I don't know why this info is not available on the latest manpage.

The info you want is under "SYMBOL DATABASE FORMAT".

ftp://ftp.eeng.dcu.ie/pub/ee454/cygwin/usr/share/doc/mlcscope-14.1.8/html/cscope.html

Comment: That link appears broken. Do you have a google phrase or working link?

Comment: Here's another link: ftp://ftp.eeng.dcu.ie/pub/ee454/cygwin/usr/share/doc/mlcscope-14.1.8/html/cscope.html

Comment: Is there any working link now?