# Getting all the functions called in the specified function

Tags: python, c, pycparser

I am using pycparser to parse a C code. My goal is that given a C code and a function name, list out all the functions called in the specified function.

I looked at the documentation for the pycparser but I couldn't find anything to solve specifically this problem.

I want the same functionality as cscope:

```
Functions called by this function: ksw_extd2_sse41

  File             Function          Line
0 ksw2_extd2_sse.c ksw_reset_extz     59 ksw_reset_extz(ez);
1 ksw2_extd2_sse.c _mm_set1_epi8      64 zero_ = _mm_set1_epi8(0);
2 ksw2_extd2_sse.c _mm_set1_epi8      65 q_ = _mm_set1_epi8(q);
3 ksw2_extd2_sse.c _mm_set1_epi8      66 q2_ = _mm_set1_epi8(q2);
4 ksw2_extd2_sse.c _mm_set1_epi8      67 qe_ = _mm_set1_epi8(q + e);
5 ksw2_extd2_sse.c _mm_set1_epi8      68 qe2_ = _mm_set1_epi8(q2 + e2);
6 ksw2_extd2_sse.c _mm_set1_epi8      69 sc_mch_ = _mm_set1_epi8(mat[0]);
7 ksw2_extd2_sse.c _mm_set1_epi8      70 sc_mis_ = _mm_set1_epi8(mat[1]);
8 ksw2_extd2_sse.c _mm_set1_epi8      71 sc_N_ = mat[m*m-1] == 0? _mm_set1_epi8(-e2) : _mm_set1_epi8(mat[m*m-1]);
9 ksw2_extd2_sse.c _mm_set1_epi8      72 m1_ = _mm_set1_epi8(m - 1);
a ksw2_extd2_sse.c kcalloc            92 mem = (uint8_t*)kcalloc(km, tlen_ * 8 + qlen_ + 1, 16);
b ksw2_extd2_sse.c memset             97 memset(u, -q - e, tlen_ * 16);
c ksw2_extd2_sse.c memset             98 memset(v, -q - e, tlen_ * 16);
d ksw2_extd2_sse.c memset             99 memset(x, -q - e, tlen_ * 16);
e ksw2_extd2_sse.c memset            100 memset(y, -q - e, tlen_ * 16);

* Lines 1-16 of 278, 263 more - press the space bar to display more *
```

Comment: Another option is let cscope do the work for you and parse the cscope databases.  This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494302/how-to-parse-a-cscopes-database may be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I am not sure how to parse the cscope.out file. And If I were to parse, wouldn't it be better to just parse source code?

Comment: I would think parsing code would be more difficult since you would have to ignore comments and quoted strings as well as handle macros and #ifdefs.  I created a tool years ago which had to store the function trees.  What I did was use the C compiler to generate assembly code for each function and then parse the result.  Since assembly has a generally small instruction set and a fixed format it was much easier to parse than C.

Comment: pycparser takes care of these things for me. So I don't have to worry about it. Moving to assembly is my back-up plan which I really want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Nested visitor will do.
Visit FuncCall in FuncDef Visitor like below.

your code will visit only 1-depth funccall.

```
class FuncCallVisitor(c_ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.callees = []  
    def visit_FuncCall(self, node):
        self.callees.append(node.name.name)

        # nested funccall
        if node.args:
            self.visit(node.args)

class FuncDefVisitor(c_ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_FuncDef(self, node):
        fcv = FuncCallVisitor()
        fcv.visit(node.body)

        print(fcv.callees) # calles has all funccall in this funcdef
```

Comment: Do you mean function definitions within a function definition? Is that even allowed in C?

Comment: no, i mean funccall in another funccall, or funccall in if statement...or something else.

Comment: Ok. Yeah It works for funccalls in loops, if statements and other blocks. 
But I don't see how it works for funccalls within funccalls. You mean the callees for main should be all the functions which will be called right?

Comment: `outer_func(inner_func(param))`
in this case, FuncCallVisitor will only visit outer_func if you don't call self.visit(node.args) or self.generic_visit().

see [link](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/pycparser/c_ast.py#L134)

Comment: Yes but the `inner_func` is a FuncCall, not a FuncDef. So the functions called in the inner function won't be listed.

Comment: `int main() {
   outer_func(inner_func())
}
int outer_func() {}
int inner_func() {}
`

in main function, there are two funccall [outer_func, inner_func]. 
but if visitor do not visit children, inner_func will be ignore. That's what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The below visitor class prints each function call for all the functions in the code base

```
class Visitor(c_ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_FuncDef(self, node):
        for stmt in node.body.block_items or []:
            if isinstance(stmt, c_ast.FuncCall):
                print (f"Function {node.decl.name} calls {stmt.name.name}")
```

Comment: There is also an example right here: https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/examples/func_calls.py

Comment: Thanks. The example is slightly different than what I am looking for. The example lists all the function calls in a file. I want all the function calls in a function definition.